# C++ While loop that stops if an array is equal too zero

Tags: c++, arrays, while-loop

I'm having a little bit problem with my game. What I want is when one out of two arrays becomes all 0's the loop will stop. Currently the loop stops when **both** arrays are equal to zero.

What I think is the problem but don't have a solution is that I have both array statements in one loop, it will run from top too bottom EVEN if array1(border1) has gotten all 0's.

What to you think?

```
void ShootAtShip(int board1[], int board2[], string names[], int cap) {
    const int hit = 0;
    int shot = 0;
    bool won = false;
    int temp;

    for (int i = 0; i < cap; i++) {
        while ((board1[i] != 0 || board2[i] != 0)) { //detects if any board has all their ships shot down
            cout << names[1] << " set a position to shoot." << endl;
            cin >> shot;
            temp = shot;

            while ((shot >= cap) || (shot < 0)) {       //detects if the number is allowed
                cout << "That number is not allowed, "<<  names[1] << " set a position to shoot." << endl;
                cin >> shot;
            }

            if (board1[shot] != 0) {
                board1[shot] = 0;
                cout << "Hit!" << endl;
            }
            else {
                cout << "You missed." << endl;
            }

            shot = 0;
            cout << names[0] << " set a position to shoot." << endl;
            cin >> shot;

            while ((shot >= cap) || (shot < 0)) {       //detects if the number is allowed
                cout << "That number is not allowed, " << names[0] << " set a position to shoot." << endl;
                cin >> shot;
            }

            if (board2[shot] != 0) {
                board2[shot] = 0;
                cout << "Hit!" << endl;
            }
            else {
                cout << "You missed." << endl;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "Testing is while loop stops";
}
```

Comment: Should `(won = true)`  actually be `(won == true)` ??

Comment: Yeah It should be but that dosnt make the problem :D, updated the code

Comment: Please format your code and remove all the unnecessary empty lines. Then try [`std::find_if_not`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find).

Comment: Please, show some respect for other users. Always take some time to format your code before posting. This time I did it for you.

Comment: Cheers mate, will think about it for next time.

Answer (score 1):

The key is that you have to check the state of the entire board at each loop iteration. Like this:

```
void ShootAtShip(int board1[], int board2[], string names[], int cap) {

for (int i = 0; i < cap; i++) 
{
    while ( 1 )
    {
       bool board1HasShips = false;
       bool board2HasShips = false;
       for ( int j = 0; j < cap; j++ ) 
       { 
          if ( board1[j] != 0 ) 
          { 
             board1HasShips = true;
             break;
          }
       }
       for ( int j = 0; j < cap; j++ ) 
       { 
          if ( board2[j] != 0 ) 
          { 
             board2HasShips = true;
             break;
          }
       }

       if ( !board1HasShips || !board2HasShips ) break; 

       // past this point we know that both boards have ships.
       // shoot at ships
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Especially when writing games, it's a good idea to try and organize your code into functions.
Personally I would do something like this:

```
bool isGameOver(int board1[],  int board2[], size_t cap)
{
    bool lost1 = true;
    bool lost2 = true;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < cap && lost1 != false; ++i)
        if (board1[i] != 0)
            lost1 = false;
    if (lost1)
        return true;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < cap && lost2 != false; ++i)
        if (board2[i] != 0)
            lost2 = false;
    return lost2;
}
```

Then use this as a conditional to break the loop.

Since you are using c++ however, why not abstract the boards into a class? This would allow you to store info such as how many ships are left in each board.

Also consider using the `std::array` class template in c++ so you won't have to pass the array size seperately and try to use `size_t` or `std::size_t` for array indexing.

Comment: Okey, but what do I have to write in the while loop to make it break the loop? **updated the code** is here http://pastebin.com/aMkXQ1nQ